# How to automatically ignore git conflicts in package.json

Tags: javascript, git, github, npm

In our app we have some shared npm packages that get updated pretty often. This leads to multiple pull requests with the same package getting a version update. So every time one of these pulls gets merged into master the other pull request will get a conflict on github. Is there a way to automatically take the highest package version so that we don't get conflicts? This slows us down a lot because we have to rerun all of our integration tests every time we fix these conflicts.

Comment: You could use a [merge driver](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes#_defining_a_custom_merge_driver) to do that kind of work.  Here's an [example](https://a3nm.net/blog/git_auto_conflicts.html) of one.  Not sure if this helps or not, but there is also [npm-merge-driver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-merge-driver).  If it doesn't directly solve the problem (and I don't think it does), it may help you devise a solution. :-)

Answer (score 0):

No there is not. GitHub does no such management and it really is not the job of a distributed source control system.